# Ping hidden-master.yahoo.com

Tags: windows, domain, ping

I am on windows 7 OS. tried the following command at the command line

ping hidden-master.yahoo.com

Following is the output:--

```
C:\Users\bilbo>ping hidden-master.yahoo.com

Pinging hidden-master.yahoo.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

The reply is coming from localhost IP i.e 127.0.0.1. Can someone please explain the output??

referred [this](http://www.robtex.com/dns/hidden-master.yahoo.com.html) and it says the name points to loopback address. there are other such names as well. Whats the practical use of having such things in place??

Answer (score 3):

They set up an DNS A record to point to 127.0.0.1. Probably for testing, or when they wanted to keep the record for future use (just change the IP when needed - the lazy admin way), but not have it point to any of their resources.

```
mulaz@sheeba ~ $ dig A hidden-master.yahoo.com

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hidden-master.yahoo.com. 172796 IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

That address is basically pointing to localhost/127.0.0.1, so after resolving, you ping your own pc.

Comment: here's the explaination i have been looking for:----    http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/dns/configuration/hidden_master.shtml